# Why is −π < atan2(y, x) ≤ π while for lines we really need only from 0 to π?

Tags: c++, c, atan2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between atan and atan2 in c++ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c)

Why is −π < atan2(y, x) ≤ π while for lines we really need only from 0 to π and what has api like atan2 but would return from 0 to pi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between atan and atan2 in c++ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c). It has "c++" in the title but all the answers apply to any language which exposes atan and atan2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common application of `atan2` is converting from cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates. And that it supports all angles is its reason of existance. Else you could just use `atan(y/x)`.

Comment: Note that `atan2()` handles the cases where `x == 0.0` correctly, which `atan(y/x)` does *not*!

Answer (score 17):

`atan2` returns all possible angles because it's not used just for drawing lines!  It's used for actual maths as well, where the difference is important.  `atan`, on the other hand, produces results in [-pi/2, +pi/2].

Comment: +1 actual math actually matters :-)