# Finding a point that is interior to a sector

Tags: c++, geometry, trigonometry, sector

SOLVED: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11712660/421178).

I'm trying to find a point that is interior to an arc so when a floodfill occurs it does not accidentally fill an area outside the arc. As long as the absolute value of the distance between the two angles: start and end; are less than PI this works (There are a couple extreme edge cases where the drawn lines are so close that the point picked is part of those lines, but that's for a different day...).

The problem I'm having is when the absolute value of the distance between the start and end angles is greater than PI the flood occurs on the exterior of the arc instead of the interior. One example of many is: if the arc starts at 0 and ends at 3PI/2 the absolute value of the distance is 3PI/2, the flood occurs between the angles as if the absolute value distance were PI/2 and floods the entire screen except the pac-man-shaped arc.

EDIT:

To avoid confusion, here is the definition of an arc according to allegro (and trigonometry in general):

> void arc(BITMAP *bmp, int x, y, fixed ang1, ang2, int r, int color);
>
> Draws a circular arc [minus the initial/terminal sides or center point] with centre [sic] x, y and radius r, in an
>   anticlockwise [sic] direction starting from the angle a1 and ending when it
>   reaches a2....Zero is to the right of the centre [sic] point, and larger
>   values rotate anticlockwise [sic] from there.

Square brackets are my notation.

I've already taken care of converting from allegro's (stupid) use of `fixed integers` to the proper `radian` values.

END EDIT

```
void Arc::Draw(BITMAP* dest, int color, bool filled, bool showCenter, bool showSides) {

    if(showSides || filled) {
        Line initial(GetX(), GetY(), GetZ(), GetStartPoint().GetX(), GetStartPoint().GetY(), GetZ(), false);
        initial.SetColor(color);

        Line terminal(GetX(), GetY(), GetZ(), GetEndPoint().GetX(), GetEndPoint().GetY(), GetZ(), false);
        terminal.SetColor(color);

        initial.Draw(dest, initial.GetColor(), false);
        terminal.Draw(dest, terminal.GetColor(), false);

    } else if(showCenter) {
        putpixel(dest, GetX(), GetY(), color);
    }

    //Draw arc first to prevent flood overflow.
    arc(dest, GetX(), GetY(), AngleConverter::RadianToFixed(_startAngle), AngleConverter::RadianToFixed(_endAngle), _radius, color);

    if(filled) {

        double distance = std::fabs(this->_endAngle - this->_startAngle);
        if(distance < a2de::A2DE_PI) {

            Line displace(GetStartPoint(), GetEndPoint(), false);
            Point displacePoint(displace.GetCenter());
            floodfill(dest, displacePoint.GetX(), displacePoint.GetY(), color);

        } else if(distance > a2de::A2DE_PI) {

            Line displace(GetStartPoint(), GetEndPoint(), false);
            Vector2D center_of_displacement(displace.GetCenter());
            Vector2D center_point(this->_center);
            Vector2D direction_of_center(center_of_displacement - center_point);

            double angle = std::atan2(direction_of_center.GetY(), direction_of_center.GetX());
            Vector2D flood_point = center_point - direction_of_center;
            flood_point += angle;

            double x = flood_point.GetX() > 0.0 ? std::ceilf(flood_point.GetX()) : std::floorf(flood_point.GetX());
            double y = flood_point.GetY() > 0.0 ? std::ceilf(flood_point.GetY()) : std::floorf(flood_point.GetY());
            floodfill(dest, x, y, color);

        } else {

            if(_startAngle == 0.0 || _endAngle == a2de::A2DE_2PI) {
                floodfill(dest, GetX(), GetY() - 1, color);
            } else if(_endAngle == 0.0 || _startAngle == a2de::A2DE_PI) {
                floodfill(dest, GetX(), GetY() + 1, color);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if you have just angle/startangle you can't define the arc, you should have 1) a signed sweep angle, or a direction clockwise/counterclockwise that says which oportion of the arc going from start to end is to be considered

Comment: @FelicePollano The clockwise/counterclockwise direction is automatically determined by the graphics library. If the start angle is greater than the end angle it is clockwise and vice versa.

Comment: You seem to use the term "arc" for what is normally called a sector

Comment: @n.m. Officially allegro only draws the arc (the curved boundary of a sector). I'm extending it allow the user to also draw the sides of the sector whose length it borders. See [arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28geometry%29)

Comment: The documentation explicitly says that the directilon is counterclockwise. This flatly contradicts your claim about the direction which I believe is (a) false and (b) the reason of your difficulties. You should talk signed angular distances (counterclockwise is positive, clockwise is negative). Never take their absolute values, it makes no sense.

Comment: @n.m. Correct, but: The code is supposed to determine if the arc length is greater than half a circle, whether the arc is from 0 to 3PI/2 or from 3PI/2 to 0 (or any infinite combinations that results in a length greater than PI) the *total length* is the same, which can never be negative, hence the absolute value is required.

Comment: You don't need any of this. Fix the direction at counterclockwise like everybody else in the known Universe, you will be glad you did. The total arc length is **NOT** determied by the absolute value of the angle difference. It is just the angle difference, end minus start, *normalized to [0, 2π)* (if it comes out negative, add 2π).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

1) Calculate Center of Arc:

```
double e = GetEndAngle();
double s = GetStartAngle();
double d = e - s;

double arc_center_x = 0.0;
double arc_center_y = 0.0;
double offset = 0.0;
if(d < 0.0) {
    offset = PI;
}
arc_center_x = (GetPosition().GetX() + std::cos(((s + e) / 2.0) + offset) * GetRadius());
arc_center_y = (GetPosition().GetY() + -std::sin(((s + e) / 2.0) + offset) * GetRadius());
_center = Vector2D(x, y);
```

2) Calculate Line from that center to the position of the sector:

```
Line l(arc_center_x, arc_center_y, p_x, p_y);
```

3) Get the mid-point of that line which is always interior to the angles of the sector:

```
double x = l.GetCenter().GetX();
double y = l.GetCenter().GetY();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, about your 'sic' comments. The circle center point *is* usually called the center also of arcs, and counter clockwise *is* the most common convention. Just as the x axis points to the right and the y axis up, and angles start at the positive x axis.

To find out if a point x,y is within a region defined in polar coordinates (r,eta) you just convert the point x_point,y_point into polar coordinates

```
r_point=sqrt((x_point-x_circle)^2 + (y_point-y_circle)^2 )
eta_point=atan2((y_point-y_circle) , (y_point-x_circle))
```

Use atan2, then you need not think about signs and pi-flips etc. [what is the difference between atan and atan2 in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c)

```
Now, is the radious within the 'sector' ?
if (r_point<r_sector) ...
```

If that's the case it's worth taking a look at the angular part: Subtract the star angle from both eta_point and the angular size of the sector

```
eta_point_new = eta_point - ang1
ang2_new = ang2 - ang1
```

Now, ang2_new is how big the sector is in the rotational direction, and eta_point_new is how far away the point is. If ang2_new is negative, it means the sector crossed the border of your angular coordinate, so you need to add 2pi to it. Then:

```
if (eta_point_new < ang2_new) 
   ... then the point is inside...
```

I'm sorry that I did not have time to test this or write it in proper C++, do with it what you like.

Answer (score 0):

The positive rotation direction is counterclockwise. I am giving pseudocode, not a real C++ code.

To determine the angle of rotation, subtract start angle from end angle. Do not take the absolute value. Normalize to the interval [0, 2π).

```
rot_angle = end_angle - start_angle;

while (rot_angle < 0)   
  rot_angle += TWO_PI;
```

Now we need to take a point halfway between the center and the start point of the arc, and rotate it around the center by the one half of the total angle of rotation we have just found:

```
start_point = rotate (point (center.x+r, center.y), center, start_angle);
interior_point = rotate (midpoint (center, start_point), center, rot_angle/2);
```

To rotate a point `pt` about an origin `o` by an angle of `theta`:

```
point rotate (point pt, point o, double theta)
{
  return point(cos(theta) * (pt.x-o.x) - sin(theta) * (pt.y-o.y) + o.x,
               sin(theta) * (pt.x-o.x) + cos(theta) * (pt.y-o.y) + o.y);

}
```

For completeness:

```
point midpoint (point p1, point p2)
{
   return point((p1.x+p2.x)/2, (p1.y+p2.y)/2);
}
```