# Haversine formula

Tags: math, trigonometry, haversine

My question is about Haversine formula as arcsin x = arctan x/(sqrt(1-x^2), therefore the formula should have atan x and not atan2 x when we convert the formula from arcsin to arctan.

θ = 2 arcsin(sqrt(a)) = 2 arctan(sqrt(a)/(sqrt(1-a)))

But in most of the previews answers has an extra 2 after atan.
Can anyone explain it to me please. Thanks

Comment: Isn't this question more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: google "atan vs atan2"; or look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c

Comment: Why do you call that the "Haversine formula"? There is no [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine#hav) in it, and [another formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is called that.

Answer (score 3):

`atan(x)` is the same as `atan2(x,1)`. `atan2(y,x)` is the angle of the point `(x,y)`, while `atan(y/x)` is the angle of the line through the origin and `(x,y)`.

The only inverse trigonometric function present as FPU on x86 CPU/FPUinstruction is `FPATAN` which implements `atan2`. Thus also `asin(x)` is implemented as `atan2(x,sqrt(1-x*x))`, `acos(x)` as `atan2(sqrt(1-x*x),x)`.