# c++ Sfml trying to move an object to the Mouse Location by a particular amount every frame

Tags: c++, mouse, move, sfml

Im kind of stuck with this problem

i created this function but for some reason i can only move the object to the right of the Player.

If i try to move the object to the Left of the Player is goes right.

here is my approach:

```
int Speed = 8;
int x = Player_x - Mouse_x;
int y = Player_y - MOuse_y; 

float deg = atan(y / x);

float erg_x = Speed * cos(deg);
float erg_y = Speed * sin(deg);
```

erg_x/y are the numbers i use at the end to move the Object.

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c), `atan` only works in the first and fourth quadrant. Since going left involves the second quadrant, this isn't going to work.

As such, you'll want to change

```
float deg = atan(y / x);
```

to

```
float deg = atan2(y, x);
```