# Convert x and y to angle in radians

Tags: r, coordinates, trigonometry, angle, points

I create a point with a random rho and theta with the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
rho <- sqrt(runif(1, 0.0, 1.0))
theta <- runif(1, 0, 2*pi)
```

obtaining `rho=0.515` and `theta=2.338`

I can get the x and y values doing `x=rho*cos(theta)` and `y=rho*sin(theta)` with `-0.358` and `0.371`, respectively

However, if I'm doing the inverse procedure

```
   r<-sqrt(x^2+y^2)
```

which results the same as rho but doing

```
   a<-atan(y/x)
```

I obtain a different result than theta.

Could you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The function tangens has a period of `pi`. So you must inspect the signs of `x` and `y` to find out the quadrant of the point. It is a mathematical (resp. logical) problem.

Comment: You mean to check if they are positive or negative? How to do it in those cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `x < 0` and `y/x = -1.036811 < 0`. Now, it means theta can only be in 2nd or 4th quadrant.

Let `tan(-z)=-tan(z)=tan(2*pi-z)=tan(pi-z)=w`, then `-z`, `pi-z`, `2*pi-z` all equals `atan(w)`, the solution is not unique in `z`.

```
atan(y/x)
#[1] -0.8034692
```

-0.8034692 is a solution means

```
pi+atan(y/x)
#[1] 2.338123
```

and

```
2*pi+atan(y/x)
#[1] 5.479716
```

are solutions as well.

```
c(tan(atan(y/x)), tan(pi+atan(y/x)), tan(2*pi+atan(y/x)))
# [1] -1.036811 -1.036811 -1.036811
```

If we are interested to find solution `0<theta<pi` then the only candidate solution is `pi+atan(y/x)=2.338123`

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `atan2`

```
atan2(y, x)
#[1] 2.338364
```

which is (almost) equal to `theta`

[Here is more discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011762/7128934)