# How to draw a rectangle around two points

Tags: python, pygame, trigonometry

I am using pygame and the math module to try and draw a rectangle around two points. Here's what I mean by that:

[image: Rectangle-controlled-by-two-points]

The distance from the points to the ends of the rectangles is specified as an attribute of the class. I have tried a lot to get this to where it is, and the angle shown is probably the only working angle. Here is my class for the rectangle:

```py
def Pol(x, y):
    """Converts rectangular coordinates into polar ones"""
    if x == 0: # This might be the source of my problems, but without it, it raises ZeroDivisionErrors at certain places
        if y >= 0:
            return [y, 90]
        else:
            return [-y, 270]
    r     = math.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    angle = (math.degrees(math.atan((y/x))))%360
    return [r, angle]

class Path(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start, end, color, width, **options):
        self.__dict__.update(options)
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.color=color
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Pass in the color of the blob, and its x and y position, width and height
        # Set the background color and make it transparent
        self.width = width

        # Draw the path
        self.redraw()

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = (self.start[0]-self.width//2+self.ix,
                                    self.start[1]-self.width//2+self.iy)
        if self.inversed:
            self.rect.y-=(math.ceil(self.image.get_rect()[3]/2)-self.iy)

    def redraw(self):
        dis, angle = Pol(self.end[0]-self.start[0], self.end[1]-self.start[1])
        dis += self.width
        _image = pygame.Surface([dis, self.width])
        _image.fill([255, 255, 255])
        _image.set_colorkey([255, 255, 255])
        pygame.draw.rect(_image, self.color, pygame.Rect(0, 0, dis, self.width))
        nangle = (180-angle)%360
        self.inversed = nangle>=180
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(_image, nangle)
        i1 = _image.get_rect()
        i2 = self.image.get_rect()
        ix = i2[2]-i1[2]
        iy = i2[3]-i1[2]
        self.ix = ix//2
        self.iy = iy//2
```

So, I pass it some points, and it takes care of all the heavy lifting, and drawing. The points I passed it in the image were `(100, 100) and (200, 200)`. I then tried it with `(300, 300) and (200, 200)`, and it performed semi-successfully:

[image: failed test]

The code is above, you can try it out with other values, but you'll see that it quickly becomes problematic. To wrap it up, my question is, is there a robust way to draw a rectangle around given two points? I have tried:

- with drawing thick lines, but pygame lines get broken up at certain angles, and have horizontal endings
- testing and playing over and over again with the values, nothing I've tried works
- changing the inverse if statement. According to what I think should happen, it's already backward

Comment: So the rule is that the major axis of the rectangle should be aligned with a line going through the two points, and it should be wide/tall enough to encompass that line segment plus a specific amount extra on each side?

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the function `math.atan()` which returns an angle in range [-pi/2, +pi/2].
Use `math.atan2()` (see [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)) which returns an angle in range [-pi,+pi]. Hence this function gives the correct angle at once, and you don't need any corrections:

<s>`angle = (math.degrees(math.atan((y/x))))%360`</s>

```py
angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
```

---

See also [What is the difference between atan and atan2 in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c)

Comment: [Some background reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c) (the Python functions mirror the C ones).