# Three.js Vector.angleTo: How to also get the bigger value

Tags: three.js

Given a vector `v1=(0,0,1)` and two vectors `v2=(1,0,0)` and `v3=(-1,0,0)` I would expect `v1.angleTo(v2)` and `v1.angleTo(v3)` to to return different results, i.e. ***1/2 PI*** and ***3/2 PI***.

However, both return ***1/2 PI***:

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

v1.angleTo(v2)
1.5707963267948966

v1.angleTo(v3)
1.5707963267948966
```

It seems that `angleTo` always returns the smaller angle, i.e. values between ***0*** and ***PI***.

How can I get the expected value/behavior?

Comment: The results you get is what I would expect, 90 degrees for both angles.

Comment: By default, an angle is always measured counterclockwisely, so I would expect one angle to be 90 degrees, the other to be 270 degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`angleTo` always returns the smaller angle. See the implementation of `angleTo` in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js.

If the angle should always be determined in one direction (i.e. either counterclockwisely or clockwisely), a simple solution for 2d vectors (or n-d vectors in a 2d plane parallel to a two-axes-plane of the coordinate system, as in the example given in the question) is:

```
var orientation = v1.x * v2.z - v1.z * v2.x;
if(orientation > 0) angle = 2*Math.PI - angle;
```

Comment: `Math.atan2(y, x)` could've been used to handle this particular case (See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011762/2228912))