# Converting from cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates and from polar to cartesian using reference

Tags: c++, math, reference

Im trying to make a simple converter using reference to convert between cartesian and polar  the problem is it gives me wrong answers and sometimes 0 ,0 . I want to know what's the problem and how can i fix it .
this is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void cartesianToPolar(int x,int y,float &r,float &q ) {
r = sqrt(x * x + y * y); q = atan(y / x);
}
void polarToCartesian(float r, float q, int &x, int &y) {
    x = r * cos(q); y = r * sin(q);
}
int main() {
    int cevap ;
    int  x = 0 , y = 0 ,xx = 0 , yy = 0;
    float r = 0 , q = 0 , rr = 0 , qq = 0 ;
    cout << "Choose please....." << endl;
    cout << "1-Cartesian -> polar "<<endl;
    cout << "2-polar ->Cartesian " << endl;
    cin >> cevap;
    if(cevap==1){
    cout << "enter x value: " ;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "enter y value: " ;
    cin >> y;
  
    cartesianToPolar(x,y,rr,qq);
    cout << "r:  " << rr << "        " << "Q: " << qq << endl;
    }
    else if (cevap==2)
    {
        cout << "enter r value : ";
        cin >> rr;
        cout << "enter Q value: ";
        cin >> qq;
        polarToCartesian(r, q, xx, yy);

        cout << "x: " << xx << "        " << "y: " << yy << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show sample in and output for good and bad cases. Explain what seems wrong about the bad cases.

Comment: Why are you alternating between int and float? There are risks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @Yunnosch 
there is no good cases i always get wrong answers like this :
enter x value: 5
enter y value: 5
r:  7.07107        Q: 0.785398 .                                         
I'm learning c++ i didn't know that its bad to use float and int together

Comment: Note that you should use `atan2(y, x)` and not `atan(y/x)`, to handle the case `x = 0`

Comment: The values you give for 5,5, are exactly what I expect as polar coordinates. Please explain what is wrong with them.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, you are right , converting from cartesian to poral works fine the problem was at the poral > cartesian part .

Comment: And you won't provide sample input and output with explanation of what makes the output wrong. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results of both of your functions should be floats, not ints:

```
void cartesianToPolar(float x, float y, float &r, float &q ) {
    r = sqrt(x * x + y * y); q = atan(y / x);
}

void polarToCartesian(float r, float q, float &x, float &y) {
    x = r * cos(q); y = r * sin(q);
}
```

The values you were computing were correct, but the result was converted to integers afterwards. Conversion to int happens by trunctation, that is, `0.1` and `0.9` all become just `0`.

You also had a typo in your polar to cartesian conversion in the main. Used the wrong variable. Correct is:

```
polarToCartesian(rr, qq, xx, yy);
```

---

Following @Yunnosch comment, you should use `atan2()` rather than `atan()`. Detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c#:%7E:text=Only%20use%20atan%20if%20the,thought%20of%20as%20y%2Fx.&text=atan2(y%2Cx)%20is,will%20give%20you%20the%20size.)

Comment: Seriously.Use atan2() instead of atan(), or woe.

Comment: @Yunnosch - added to the post, haven't really used them in C++ or C so was unaware.

Comment: @MrXQ - gladly!

Comment: It is fine. I should dial down on the "woe". It is just so amazingly more convenient, because of being made especially for this use case.

Comment: It could be a deliberate design decision to have the Cartesian coordinates integer only. The fix would be a cast  `sqrt(double(x * x + y * y)), atan2((double)y, (double)x);`