# How to convert from atan to atan2?

Tags: python, function, trigonometry

In Python, if one wanted to create the effect of atan2() from the atan() function, how would one go about this? For example, if I had cartesian coordinates (x, y) and wanted to find the arctan of (x, y) using the atan() function such that it worked in all quadrants, so regardless of the sign of x or y, how could I do this without using the atan2() function? In the example of converting between cartesian and polar:

```
def cartopol(x, y):
    r = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
    p = math.atan(y/x)
    return(r,p)
```

This formula for returning the correct angle in radians would not currently work using the atan() function, so what must change?

Comment: Why don't you just use `atan2`? It's bad practice to try and rewrite built-ins, re-enventing the wheel.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c) explains a lot of the differences between `atan` and `atan2`

Comment: If you know the signs of y and x, then you can manually add `pi` or `-pi` to `math.atan(y/x)` depending on the signs of `y` and `x` to get the right value. Obviously, this it not recommended since you already have a `math.atan2` function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between atan and atan2 in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283406/what-is-the-difference-between-atan-and-atan2-in-c)

Comment: @rafaelc Can you explain this concept to me please? This is exactly what I need to know. Thanks.

Comment: @rafaelc: You should add your comments as an answer.

Comment: @MrGeek: I learned pretty much everything I know about C by rewriting functions from the standard library. Of course I wouldn't use these rewritten functions in production code. But I also wouldn't recommend skipping a good learning opportunity under the pretense that it's "bad practice".

Comment: @Stef I understand your point, I do this too, I just assumed the OP was making this for use in production code, other than that, I agree with you, I re-invent the wheel lots of times for fun, and it's pretty rewarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, `math.atan` only works for quadrants 1 and 4. For quadrants 2 and 3 (i.e. for x < 0), then you'd have to add or subtract pi (180 degrees) to get to quadrants 1 and 4 and find the respective value for the theta. In code, it means that

```
if (y < 0 and x < 0): 
    print(math.atan(y/x) - math.pi)
elif (y > 0 and x < 0): 
    print(math.atan(y/x) + math.pi)
```

For more reference, take a look at [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). The other two use cases are those in which `x > 0`, which works well with `atan`.